# Drools Decision Table Default Value

Tags: drools

How to set Default Value in Drools Decision table do an action without condition

Rule Compilation error $cs cannot be resolved

eg:

[image]

Comment: Well, what do you expect? This says call setSavings and setEligibility - somewhere. How should the computer know where "somewhere" is?

Comment: Yup you are right please find the solution below

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval(true) which will help to declare the $cs in the Condition

[image]